# How to TeX an arrow with vertical stroke?

Tags: math-mode

It is really strange, but LaTeX doesn't seem to include any tag for an arrow with vertical stroke (unicode character 21F8), used in mathematics to represent a partial function between sets (as reported in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Domain_of_a_partial_function) from Wiki.en). Do you know any workaround to this? I tried something like

```
\newcommand{\pto}{\to\hspace{-xyz cm}\shortmid \hspace{xyz cm}}
```

(for different values of xyz) but the outcome is not very satisfactory. Thank you in advance for any help.

P.S.: the symbol should fit in mathematical equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to use `\pfun` in package [`oz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/objectz) as listed in the overview [here](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/oz-symbols.pdf).

Comment: Great! I didn't know that package before, thank you too.

Comment: Small warning to any users who use this approach. When I imported the `oz` package to use `\pfun`, for some reason it replaced some of my other math symbols. For example where I had an integral using `\int` it was rendered as the set intersection symbol instead! I used the other solution by egreg and redefined the `\pfun` command myself.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a possible way

```
\newcommand\pto{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$\mapstochar$\hfil\cr$\to$\cr}}}
```

Note that the definition of `oz.sty` is equivalent to

```
\newcommand\pfun{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$\mapstochar\mkern5mu$\hfil\cr$\to$\cr}}}
```

so it differs from the former only by a slight shift to the left of the bar.

---

A complete and better implementation using also the shift in `oz.sty`; this one works also in subscripts and superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pto}{}% just for safety
\newcommand{\pgets}{}% just for safety

\DeclareRobustCommand{\pto}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\p@to@gets\to}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pgets}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\p@to@gets\gets}}

\newcommand{\p@to@gets}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1\mapstochar\mkern5mu$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1\to$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\pto B\pgets C$

$\scriptstyle A\pto B\pgets C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note for latex newbies, you need to copy this definition somewhere, and then you can use it in maths expressions like `$\pfun$`

Comment: @rleelr Back then the style was different. I took the occasion for improving the answer. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 6):

With `unicode-math` package (requires XeTeX or LuaTeX) and a proper Unicode math font, you can access that Unicode arrow (and a gazillion of other Unicode math symbols):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
$\nvrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Unicode: `\char"21F8`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21f8/index.htm)

[image]

Another solution (which I use now)

% Partial function character from Z-notation
\newcommand\pfun{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$\mapstochar$\hfil\cr$\to$\cr}}}